# Why is the data in the collection view cells gets changing when I scroll the table view or the collection view?

Tags: swift

I am trying to embed the collection view in the table view. When the page gets loaded I will retrieve the data field by field from the database and reloads the data whenever I retrieve the single field from the database. Here while reloading the table view I need to check the value i.e "oneimage" so if that value is not empty it should set to the collection view cell. The problem is whenever I scroll the table view the data in the collection view cells get swapped. Here is the code below

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import SDWebImage

struct values {
 var quesvalue: String
 var answvalue: String
 var ImageUrl = [String]()
}


class QuestionsCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!
 @IBOutlet weak var card: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var answer: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var speakbutton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionviewh: NSLayoutConstraint!
 var imageArray = [String] ()
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
 }
 override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

 }
}

extension QuestionsCell {
 func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: UICollectionViewDataSource & 
  UICollectionViewDelegate>(dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {
    collectionview.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionview.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    print("collectionviee.tag",collectionview.tag,row)
    collectionview.tag = row
    collectionview.contentOffset = .zero // Stops collection view if it was scrolling.
 }
}
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{

 @IBOutlet weak var backcard: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!
 var task: URLSessionDataTask?
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

 }
 override func prepareForReuse(){
    imageview.image = nil
 }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var JSONArray = [String:Any]()
var quesArray = [String]()
var ansArray = [String]()
var answer : String!
var imagesarray = [String]()
var open : [values] = []
var oneimage = [String]()
var storedOffsets = [Int: CGFloat]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.delegate = self

    tableview.rowHeight=UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableview.estimatedRowHeight=150
    Firestore.firestore().collection("User").document("7ngPwZin2wg7j5JZtI0hKJO8uSA2").collection("Popop").document("7ngPwZin2wg7j5JZtI0hKJO8uSA2").collection("Answers").document("Earlyyears").getDocument() { (document, error) in
                        if let document = document, document.exists {
                            self.open.removeAll()
                            self.imagesarray.removeAll()
                            self.oneimage.removeAll()
                            if let b1 = document.data()!["Name"] as? [String: Any] {
                                print("1",b1)
                                if let firstName = b1["Answer"] as? String {
                                    print("firstName is",firstName)

                                    if firstName != "No answer recorded"{
                                        self.answer = firstName
                                        self.ansArray.append(firstName)
                                        if let imageurlarray = b1["ImageURL"] as? [String] {
                                            self.imagesarray = imageurlarray
                                            print("imageurl array in meaning feild is",imageurlarray)
                                            self.open.insert(values(quesvalue: self.quesArray[0],answvalue: self.answer,ImageUrl: self.imagesarray), at: 0)
                                            self.tableview.reloadData()
                                        }


                                     }
                                }


                            }
                            if let b2 = document.data()!["Meaning"] as? [String: Any] {
                                print("1")
                                if let firstName = b2["Answer"] as? String {
                                    print("firstName is",firstName)

                                    if firstName != "No answer recorded"{
                                        self.answer = firstName
                                        self.ansArray.append(firstName)
                                        if let imageurlarray = b2["ImageURL"] as? [String] {
                                            self.imagesarray = imageurlarray
                                            print("imageurl array in meaning feild is",imageurlarray)
                                            self.open.insert(values(quesvalue: self.quesArray[1],answvalue: self.answer,ImageUrl: self.imagesarray), at: 1)
                                            self.tableview.reloadData()
                                        }


                                    }

                                }

                            }


                        } else {
                                print("Document does not exist")
                            }
                        }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("ansArry.count is",open.count)
    return open.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("entered into cellfor row at")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! QuestionsCell
    print("quesrray,ansArray are",quesArray,ansArray,open)
    if open.count > indexPath.row{

        cell.question.text = open[indexPath.row].quesvalue
        cell.answer.text = open[indexPath.row].answvalue
        print("cell.ques.text",cell.question.text)


        oneimage = open[indexPath.row].ImageUrl
        print("onimage before checking",oneimage)
        if !oneimage.isEmpty{
            print("entered into oneimage not empty",oneimage)
            cell.collectionview.isHidden = false
            cell.collectionviewh.constant  = 160

   cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row)


        }
        else{
            print("dont show collection view")
            cell.collectionview.isHidden = true
            cell.collectionviewh.constant  = 0
        }

    }
    else{
        print("<")
    }

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("imagesarray.count is",oneimage.count)

        print("oneimage.count")
        return oneimage.count


}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: CollectionViewCell = (collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell)!

  if oneimage.count > indexPath.row{
        if oneimage != [""] {
            let image = oneimage[indexPath.row]
            print("oneimage is",image)
            print("entered into oneimage not empty")
            cell.imageview.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image))
         }
       }

    return cell

}
```

Here are the screenshots of my output.

[image: The following image is visible when the page gets loaded]
[image: The following page is visible when I scroll the collection view or table view]

Comment: move setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate  in willDisplayCell.

Comment: It is called reusing ('aka' recycling).

Comment: @KeshuRai - Do you mean this line "cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row)"

Comment: yes............

Comment: @KeshuRai - I tried this but now I can't see the images in the collection view cell.Simply collection view with empty space. Actually what I have observed is it is not entering into that method.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini - Ok. How to solve it

Comment: You should provide a **Minimum** issue reproducible code so others can show you how. I can just hint you that you should validate the actual index path of the cell after image downloaded.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini - I did not get your point. By the way, I have reduced the code can you please edit there. So that I can know. Please it is very urgent

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini - Is there any probability of using the collection view in the view did load method.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is because of the reusability. That means when a cell goes out from bottom/top, the same cell (containing the previous setup) comes in from top/bottom. So if you set something async, like a remote image on it, it may be visible on incorrect cell. You should make sure you are selecting correct cell when you are about to set the image on it.

For example you should change this:

```
cell.imageview.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image))
```

to something like this:

```
(collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell)?.imageview.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image))
```

This will ask the `collectionView` for the real cell instead of the reused one. I don't know how `sd` library works, but you may want to do this in the `completionHandler` of the library.

Maybe [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwjDgqmQmajmAhVPTsAKHfffCPoQFjADegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.cobeisfresh.com%2Fdealing-with-complex-table-views-in-ios-and-keeping-your-sanity-ff5fee1fbb83&usg=AOvVaw1MlG4ZL3U0nH1wNkTVnpGB) could help you.

Comment: Now I cant see images in the collection view cell.                                                                                                     if oneimage.count > indexPath.row{
            if oneimage != [""] {
                let image = oneimage[indexPath.row]
                print("oneimage is",image)
                if image != ""{
                   
                    (collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell)?.imageview.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image))
                }
            }
         }

Comment: Can you please tell me more detailed way